# How to overlay a dynamic label on a video in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, video, dynamic, timer

I'm trying to overlay a dynamic label (I want it to be a timer) on a video that's being recorded.

I need an iphone to record a video and overlay a timer right on this video and export it. So as a result I'll get a video with a timer overlayed, that'll be showing video length.

What's the best way to do it? I know how to overlay just a label on video, but I can't make it dynamic (a timer perhaps). What would you use? What's the best way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried. Are you using AVFoundation and Core animation tool?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the text for the label based on a timer in code. For example:

```
var currentTimeCounter = 0
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { (returnedTimer) in
    label.text = String(currentTimeCounter)
    currentTimeCounter += 1
}
```

`withTimeInterval`: the number of seconds between each call of the block. If you want to measure parts of a second, pass a decimal. For example, passing 0.1 will call the function every tenth of a second.

Comment: Yea that would show the timer, but it wouldn't save the timer overlayed on the video when you save it on your phone :(